# canopy express 64 bit don't start

Tags: python-2.7, installation, 64-bit, enthought

I have a problem. I 've just installed Entought Canopy Express x64 on my Windows 7 machine. The installation has no issues or warnings.  But I can't start it. I tried both shortcut and running canopy.exe. Even restarting OS have not helped. I have other python distribution installed but no one in PATH.

Comment: Not familiar with how Canopy is delievered/installed, but I've had similar issues when a Python-based 'program' has silent errors during install. If I were you, I'd try re-checking Canopy to see if I meet all dependency requirements etc.,maybe attempt to uninstall/reinstall, possible through other means if multiple options are available.

Comment: Thanks, pallandt! Unfortunately, I tried all of these with no success :-(